# Java APIs return well formatted JSON for success and failure including authentication errors

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, spring-java-config

Not an expert in developing APIs so need some help/advice from the community.
I have an application that used Java Spring MVC for APIs. I am using ResponseEntity to return responses back to anyone who would use the APIs (third-party or UI).
Example of my API

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Test/")
public ResponseEntity<TestGroup> getTestsById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    TestGroup testGroup = testService.getTestById(id);  //calls a service that returns test from the db
    if(testGroup != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity(testGroup, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

I have other APIs similar to this. My question is whether there are any frameworks or ways so that I can make my APIs return JSON response for errors or success in a well formatted JSON. Example

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request",
  "description": "There were no credentials found."
}

{
  "code": 200,
  "data": "{<JSON blob of the object to be returned>}"
}
```

Also,
Have implemented a Filter to check for session information (think of them as oauth tokes) for authentication before any of the routes are mapped. I need this process of error handling to work at that stage too, so that if there is an expired token or invalid token I get back a well formatted JSON. Example

```
{
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "description": "The token used in the request is incorrect or has expired."
}
```

Right now I get the default message Spring's authentication Filter throws in the form of an HTML

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.50 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Access is denied</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Access is denied</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
com.test.security.CookieAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CookieAuthenticationFilter.java:95)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
</pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.50 logs.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.50</h3></body></html>
```

Apologize for not communicating this, I am not using spring security for the APIs and my web.xml for the filter looks like this

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

<display-name>Webapp</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.test.spring.config</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.spring.config=</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Here is how the security configuration is handled.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private AbstractConfiguration configurationManager;

    public SecurityConfiguration() {
        super(true);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/health/**").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/complete/**").permitAll().and()
                .addFilterBefore(cookieAuthenticationFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class).authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("tests");
    }

    @Bean
    public GenericFilterBean cookieAuthenticationFilter() {
        if (System.getProperty("noauth") != null) {
            return new SecurityFilterMock();
        } else {
            return new CookieAuthenticationFilter(redisTemplate());
        }
    }
}
```

As per suggestions if you read below, I have made the following EntryPoint class to handle the token authentication and display a JSON

```
public class TokenAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenAuthenticationEntryPoint.class);

@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    log.info(String.format("Unauthorized access with session id '%s'",
            request.getSession().getId()));

    ErrorHandler errorResponse = new ErrorHandler();
    // populate your response object with all the info you need
    errorResponse.setCode(401);
    errorResponse.setDescription("The token used in the request is incorrect or invalid.");
    errorResponse.setMessage("Unauthorized");

    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value()); 
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(errorResponse));
}
}
```

Any suggestions or directions would be really appreciated

Comment: You could have all your controller methods (REST endpoints) return a custom bean that has the properties you need such as "code", "message", "description", "data". Spring would automatically convert the bean to JSON if you have the correct annotations such as "@RestController" / "@ResponseBody" and a library such as Jackson on the classpath. You would need to ensure your client accepts "application/json" content-type

Comment: That makes absolute sense. Thank you for the suggestion. I have kinda implemented something similar using "@ControllerAdvice" and "@ResponseStatus" which would handle the controller based errors and success possibly.

Comment: Do you have any insight about handling errors at the Spring Filter level which executes before the controllers? I have a custom filter that extends GenericFilterBean which validates session tokens for validity before hitting any routes. The doFilter() does all the magic to validate it. Right now if I have an expired token or invalid token, I get the Apache Tomcat Error report as I posted above. What do I need to do to return a well formatted JSON "code", "message", "description" instead of that unwanted stacktrace all the time. Any suggestions?  @Owl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return JSON formatted errors to authentication with Spring you can have a look at my answer here: [How to return JSON response for unauthorized AJAX calls instead of login page as AJAX response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280815/how-to-return-json-response-for-unauthorized-ajax-calls-instead-of-login-page-as/33297418#33297418)

Basically, you'll have to tweak authentication mechanism and redefine the entry point to properly hendle the response.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, I am not using spring security for the APIs. I do not have a security-context file in the project. Also to add a little more context, there is another app that does the login and returns a token which my application uses to validate routes. I can post the Filter code if you like. There is another question I had asked [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402512/handle-authentication-and-suppress-tomcat-html-stack-trace-for-a-custom-genericf)

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand you weren't using Spring security. I suppose you register the filter in the web.xml and the relatove access voter and such in the Spring context? Would be helpful if you could add to your original question both the web.xml and the application context.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my post for more clarity.

Comment: I also stand corrected I am using spring-security but I do not use a security-context.

Comment: @Ashley having or not a file named security-context.xml doesn't matter, actually. What's important is that you have registered the Spring security filter and the HTTP security. Now, I'm not used to the Java style configuration, always used the XML one, but I suppose the two things are equivalent. I'd guess you have to add a bean definition (the entry point) and to tweak the method `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception` to inject youor bean into Spring security chain; as for the basic concept of my answer, it should still work.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that security-context.xml. Was ignorant about that. I am going to try your suggestion.

Comment: can you please suggest how I could tweak my configure method and inject the bean (that I create in my SecurityConfiguration.java) into Spring security chain? Right now as you see, custom cookie filter is injected in the configure().

Comment: This is what I added to configure() `.and()
    .httpBasic()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(myBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint())    @Bean 
 public BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint myBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
  MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
  entryPoint.setRealmName("Authenticate Session");
  return entryPoint;
 }`    But MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint class is not being called and I still get back the tomcat logs.

Comment: @Ashley Sounds about right, in all fairness. You could also try a more straightforward `http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(myBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint());` but as I said, I've started with Spring years ago, and I'm so used to XML configuration that I never used the new Java style one. Anyway, could you add to your original post the code of the entry point?

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion. I got it to work using `.and()
    .exceptionHandling()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(myBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint())`. My code for the entry point is exactly the same as your code in the link you sent, no changes just to see if it could do the job. However, I get a null pointer when at `httpMessageConverter.write(response, mediaType, serverHttpResponse);` since the mediaType is null. I am not sure how would I configure httpMessageConverters in java config with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as the super class. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to tweak your class and display the JSON without using httpMessageConverters. Have posted my code above. However, is there a way to validate if an api route does not exist using the same entry point technique? Right now when I try to access a route but misspell it, I get the tomcat logs again but want to display a json for the same which says that the "Route does not exist". Any thoughts?

Comment: @Ashley that is a thing that depends on the request header "accept". The client needs to set it to "application/json" in order to be recognized as a json request. Anyway, null pointers can be easily handled in the code.

Comment: @Ashley we're now going a bit OP, but no matter. You mean to give errors for HTTP codes such as 404? If so, then have a look at Spring `@ExceptionHandler` and to `@ControllerAdvice`. Those kind of errors don't need such a deep approache and can be addressed at a controller level. P.S.: if the solution worked, can you please accept the answer?

Comment: Thanks again for all the suggestions and directions. I will look into the annotations you suggested. I have accepted the answer.